# How does optimization work?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've created an object with some attributes and applied some functions to carry out some information from that object. After that, I did the same operation again.
And I wondered how efficiency changed when I did same task the second time.

```
const dragonEvents = [
  { type: 'attack', value: 12, target: 'player-dorkman'},
  { type: 'yawn', value: 40},
  { type: 'eat',  target: 'horse'},
  { type: 'attack', value: 23, target: 'player-fluffykins'},
  { type: 'attack', value: 12, target: 'player-dorkman'},
]
console.time('firstTimer')
const totalDamageOnDorkman = dragonEvents
  .filter(function (event) {
    return event.type === 'attack'
  })
  .filter(function (event) {
    return event.target === 'player-dorkman'
  })
  .map(function (event) {
    return event.value
  })
console.timeEnd('firstTimer')

console.time('secondTimer')
const totalDamageOnDorkman1 = dragonEvents
  .filter(function (event) {
    return event.type === 'attack'
  })
  .filter(function (event) {
    return event.target === 'player-dorkman'
  })
  .map(function (event) {
    return event.value
  })
console.timeEnd('secondTimer')
```

And efficiency resualts are the following:

```
firstTimer: 0.442ms
secondTimer: 0.087ms
```

The question is, what did cause this efficiency growth, and where I can read about that mechanism precisely?

Comment: Different user agents are implemented differently and whatever optimizations are implemented are native.

Comment: `firstTimer: 0.000ms, secondTimer: 0.000ms` on chrome. Compiler and special optimization dependant very likely. Also the topic is slightly misleading towards a more general question.

Comment: Great question! As a completely unrelated point, you can use lambda notation for anonymous functions that just return a value `.filter( event => event.target === 'player-dorkman' )`

Comment: I get no meaningful difference in Chrome--0.069 for the first and 0.070ms for the second.

Comment: I didn't mention, but I run my code using Node.js v6.8.1